# android UI not showing up while processing other data

Tags: android

I'm trying to read in 17 images from the Internet while displaying a splash screen. However with the following code, the splash screen does not show up at all during the processing. It goes black, finishes and transits to the next activity. I thought calling setContentView before the processing code is good enough but apparently not.

What am I missing?

Thanks for your help.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);


    // read the bitmaps
    // Open a new URL and get the InputStream to load data from it

    // Start reading the XML and filling the arrays
    for (int i=0; i<16; i++) {
        try {
            URL aURL = new URL (districtImage[i]);
            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            // Buffered is always good for performance
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            districtBitmap[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            bis.close();
            is.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            Log.e ("DEBUGTAG","Cannot load remote image", e);
        }
    }
    ... some more code to transit to next activity...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do networking operations inside `onCreate`, you are blocking the UI thread until they complete. Nothing will show up on the screen before `onCreate` returns. See the article [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) for various ways to avoid this problem.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply. Let me read that and come back.

Comment: Read through AsyncTask. That's the way to go. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing "Start reading the XML and filling the arrays" in onResume() of your activity and then transit to next activity? And do reading from network in threads/async tasks.

Comment: Why would onResume() be involked when things are running in onCreate()?

Comment: UI is not shown to user till onResume() is invoked. So keep your onCreate() 'light' and do heavy stuff after onResume() is called.

Comment: I moved the code to onResume(). Screen goes blank, did all the processing, splash screen shows, then move on to next activity right away. The only difference is now the splash screen shows for a second (I used animation to slow it down so that I could see it). I believe threading is the way to go on my problem.